# AspectJ: Intercept return result of method inside another method

Tags: java, aspectj, pointcut, pointcuts

I need help to write some Aspectj advice on this particular case:

Suppose we have this class:

```
package org.group;

public class Person {

   public void method1(String id, String number) {
       //some code
       List<String> list = getList(number);
       //some code
   }

   public List<String> getList(String number) {
       return Arrays.asList(number);
   }

}
```

I want to create an Aspectj advice into method1 to get the result of getList. I try this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* org.group.Person.getList(..))")
public void methodGetList() {

}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "methodGetList()", returning = "result")
public void afterMethodGetList(JoinPoint joinPoint, List<String> result) {
    System.out.println("I can see the list result: " + result.toString());
}
```

This advice works on all executions of getList method, but what I want exactly, is to get the result inside the method1 call to get an information with the method1's id , for example like this:

---

'**I can see the list result [4] for the person with id : XXX**'

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to limit your pointcut to the executions within the control flow - `cflow()` - of the calling method and also bind the calling method's parameter of interest via `args()`.

**Application:**

```java
package org.group;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {
  public void method1(String id, String number) {
    // some code
    List<String> list = getList(number);
    // some code
  }

  public List<String> getList(String number) {
    return Arrays.asList(number);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Should not be intercepted
    new Person().getList("22");
    // Should be intercepted
    new Person().method1("John Doe", "11");
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.List;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(* org.group.Person.getList(..))")
  public void methodGetList() {}

  @Pointcut("execution(* org.group.Person.method1(..)) && args(id, *)")
  public void methodMethod1(String id) {}

  @AfterReturning(
    pointcut = "methodGetList() && cflow(methodMethod1(id))",
    returning = "result"
  )
  public void afterMethodGetList(JoinPoint joinPoint, String id, List<String> result) {
    System.out.println(
      "I can see the list result " + result +
      " for the person with id " + id
    );
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
I can see the list result [11] for the person with id John Doe
```

Comment: Does Spring AOP support cflow?

Comment: No, it does not, but you can use AspectJ via LTW in Spring. BTW, why are you tagging your question _aspectj_ and _pointcut_, but not _spring-aop_ and/or _spring_? BTW2, self-invocation like in your example would also not be intercepted in Spring AOP. So just stick with AspectJ, IMO it is better in all respects and also works without Spring.

Comment: It is not my question, I just commented on your answer, when I noticed AspectJ syntax within the Spring Aspect. I think you need to explain OP about LTW.

Comment: @fg78nc what Spring Aspect? How does Spring comes into this question or answer?

Comment: My bad, I thought he is asking about Spring.

Comment: Oh, @fg78nc, you are not even the original author. I mistook you for him. So the question is even more unrelated and confusing. I am happy we clarified this. So the question tags are just right, only the comment was irritating. :-)

Comment: @kriegaex I was confused because due `@AspectJ` syntax, which I see more often in Spring. Accustomed to AspectJ native syntax. did not pay much attention to tags.Cheers!

Comment: You have my sympathy. I also clearly prefer the native syntax, unlike so many others, and I will never understand why they choose otherwise. But if someone asks with annotation-based syntax (which was borrowed by Spring from AspectJ, BTW), alas I shall answer in the same style. But if I have a choice, why would I package the aspect syntax into a string instead of freely writing in my IDE editor with syntax highlighting etc.?